# Why is mutating an owned value and borrowed reference safe in Rust?

Tags: rust

In [How does Rust prevent data races when the owner of a value can read it while another thread changes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688018/how-does-rust-prevent-data-races-when-the-owner-of-a-value-can-read-it-while-ano), I understand I need `&mut self`, when we want to mutate an object, even when the method is called with an owned value.

But how about primitive values, like `i32`? I ran this code:

```
fn change_aaa(bbb: &mut i32) {
    *bbb = 3;
}

fn main() {
    let mut aaa: i32 = 1;
    change_aaa(&mut aaa); // somehow run this asynchronously
    aaa = 2; // ... and will have data race here
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is this safe in a non concurrent situation?
   According to [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html), if we think of the owned value as a pointer, it is not safe according the following rules, however, it compiles.

   > Two or more pointers access the same data at the same time.
   >
   > At least one of the pointers is being used to write to the data.
   >
   > There’s no mechanism being used to synchronize access to the data.
2. Is this safe in a concurrent situation?
   I tried, but I find it hard to put `change_aaa(&mut aaa)` into a thread, according to [Why can't std::thread::spawn accept arguments in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70082393/why-cant-stdthreadspawn-accept-arguments-in-rust/70082474#70082474) and [How does Rust prevent data races when the owner of a value can read it while another thread changes it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688018/how-does-rust-prevent-data-races-when-the-owner-of-a-value-can-read-it-while-ano). However, is it designed to be hard or impossible to do this, or just because I am unfamiliar with Rust?

Comment: It's actually quite easy to move it to a different thread, but it's also safe, because if you run `change_aaa` in another thread, `aaa` will implicitly be copied, because `i32` implements the [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) trait. If you were to use something that doesn't you'd get a compile error akin to `value borrowed here after move`. [Demonstration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9fac4d3f3f4aa9d1f7eadf2a3229df10)

Comment: [Non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251487/what-are-non-lexical-lifetimes) allow you to borrow mutably several times in the same scope, as long as these borrows do not overlap. In your example, when you execute `aaa = 2;`, `change_aaa()` has already ended and there is no data race.

Comment: The book shows how to create a situation with concurrency on [chapter 16](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html). But concurrency is not necessary to trigger unsafety here ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0c9ba87d0717313ca47d984fc6e3511f)).

Answer (score 4):

The signature of `change_aaa` **doesn't** allow it to move the reference into another thread. For example, you might imagine a `change_aaa()` implemented like this:

```
fn change_aaa(bbb: &mut i32) {
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        *bbb = 100; // ha ha ha - kaboom!
    });
}
```

But the above doesn't compile. This is because, after desugaring the [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), the full signature of `change_aaa()` is:

```
fn change_aaa<'a>(bbb: &'a mut i32)
```

The lifetime annotation means that `change_aaa` must support references of any lifetime `'a` chosen by the caller, even a very short one, such as one that invalidates the reference as soon as `change_aaa()` returns. And this is exactly how `change_aaa()` is called from `main()`, which can be desugared to:

```
let mut aaa: i32 = 1;
{
    let aaa_ref = &mut aaa;
    change_aaa(aaa_ref);
    // aaa_ref goes out of scope here, and we're free to mutate
    // aaa as we please
}
aaa = 2; // ... and will have data race here
```

So the lifetime of the reference is short, and ends just before the assignment to `aaa`. On the other hand, `thread::spawn()` requires a function bound with `'static` lifetime. That means that the closure passed to `thread::spawn()` must either only contain owned data, or references to `'static` data (data guaranteed to last until the end of the program). Since `change_aaa()` accepts `bbb` with with lifetime shorter than `'static`, it cannot pass `bbb` to `thread::spawn()`.

To get a grip on this you can try to come up with imaginative ways to write `change_aaa()` so that it writes to `*bbb` in a thread. If you succeed in doing so, you will have found a bug in rustc. In other words:

> However, is it designed to be hard or impossible to do this, or just because I am unfamiliar with Rust?

It is designed to be impossible to do this, except through types that are explicitly designed to make it safe (e.g. `Arc` to prolong the lifetime, and `Mutex` to make writes data-race-safe).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this safe in a non concurrent situation? According to this post, if we think owned value if self as a pointer, it is not safe according the following rules, however, it compiles.
>
> > Two or more pointers access the same data at the same time.
> > At least one of the pointers is being used to write to the data.
> > There’s no mechanism being used to synchronize access to the data.

It is safe according to those rules: there is one pointer accessing data at line 2 (the pointer passed to `change_aaa`), then that pointer is deleted and another pointer is used to update the local.

> Is this safe in a concurrent situation? I tried, but I find it hard to put `change_aaa(&mut aaa)` into a thread, according to post and post. However, is it designed to be hard or impossible to do this, or just because I am unfamiliar with Rust?

While it is possible to put `change_aaa(&mut aaa)` in a separate thread using [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html), the corresponding lifetimes will ensure the compiler rejects any code trying to modify `aaa` while that thread runs. You will essentially have this failure:

```rust
fn main(){
    let mut aaa: i32 = 1;
    let r = &mut aaa;
    aaa = 2;
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `aaa` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
9  |     let r = &mut aaa;
   |             -------- borrow of `aaa` occurs here
10 |     aaa = 2;
   |     ^^^^^^^ assignment to borrowed `aaa` occurs here
11 |     println!("{}", r);
   |                    - borrow later used here
```